# Basic GUI Validation task

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, user-interface

i have been given a set of tasks which is shown below I have managed to do everything required other than the validation. I have also included my code so far. I would love some help. thanks. from this i am currently using eclipse to create this.

This process should involve validating the contents of the file against the expected format. If something is missing then an `error` message should be shown to the user in the form of a dialogue box.

```
 public class BasicGUI extends JFrame {


    private JPanel contentPane;
    public JTextArea inputTextArea;
    public JTextArea outputGraphicalArea;

    JSplitPane splitPane;




    public BasicGUI() {

        createMenuBar();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));




        inputTextArea = new JTextArea();
        outputGraphicalArea = new JTextArea();

        JScrollPane scrollPanelLeft = new JScrollPane(inputTextArea);
        JScrollPane scrollPanelRight = new JScrollPane(outputGraphicalArea);

        JSplitPane applicationpanel = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                scrollPanelLeft, scrollPanelRight);

        applicationpanel.setOneTouchExpandable(true);

        contentPane.add(applicationpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        applicationpanel.setResizeWeight(0.5); 


        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setTitle(" Requirement 1 + 2 ");
        setSize(350, 250);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);


    }
    private void createMenuBar() {

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
       JMenuItem aboutMenu = new JMenuItem("About");
       aboutMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
             {
                if (dialog == null) 
                dialog = new AboutDialog(BasicGUI.this);
                dialog.setVisible(true); 
             }
          });                
        ImageIcon iconLoad = new ImageIcon("load_icon.png");
        JMenuItem loadMi = new JMenuItem("Load", iconLoad);


        loadMi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                inputTextArea.setText("No File Chosen");
             else
             {
                 File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                 Scanner scan = null;
                try {
                    scan = new Scanner(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 String info = "";
                 while (scan.hasNext())
                    info += scan.nextLine() + "\n";


                 inputTextArea.setText(info);
             }


        }
        });

       ImageIcon iconSave = new ImageIcon("save_icon.png");
       JMenuItem saveMi = new JMenuItem("Save", iconSave);


     ImageIcon iconExit = new ImageIcon("exit_icon.png");
     JMenuItem exitMi = new JMenuItem("Exit", iconExit);

       exitMi.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);       
       exitMi.setToolTipText("Exit application");

       exitMi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E,
           ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
       exitMi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               System.exit(0);
           }
    });


       fileMenu.add(loadMi);
       fileMenu.add(saveMi);
       fileMenu.addSeparator();
       fileMenu.add(exitMi);
       menubar.add(fileMenu);
       menubar.add(aboutMenu);
       menubar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
       menubar.add(helpMenu);
       setJMenuBar(menubar);  
    }


       private AboutDialog dialog;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class AboutDialog extends JDialog
    {
       public AboutDialog(JFrame owner)
       {
          super(owner, "About DialogBox", true);


          add(
                  new JLabel
                  (
                        "<html><h1><i>Requirement 1 –  Basic GUI creation </i></h1><hr>The first requirement for this assignment is to implement the basic Graphical User Interface (GUI) as an initial prototype. At this point the application will be an “empty shell”, with very limited functionality. However it should consist of an application frame, a menu bar and a main application panel split into two halves.  One half should be capable of displaying a textual representation of the file being processed, and the other will (eventually) show the graphical representation of that data<hr>The text panel should be capable of showing all information read from the text file (see requirement 2), but in an aesthetically pleasing manner. You may choose to use labels and associated values to show heading information, such as the 'Title'.  The data should be shown within some kind of text window (with scrollbars when required).<hr>The menu bar should consist of a 'File' and 'Help' menu.  The File menu should include options for loading, saving and exiting the application.  The 'Help' menu should contain an option for showing a dialogue box which identifies information about the application. At this point however only the 'Exit' and 'About' options need to work<hr>The application should be designed so that it uses layout managers where appropriate, and can be sensibly resized by the user.  The menu options should also include short-cuts and icons where appropriate.<hr><h1><i>Requirement 2 –  Loading and parsing </i></h1><hr>Once a basic GUI is available the next requirement is to add the ability to actually load, parse and display the data. The 'File | Load' option should show a file open dialogue allowing selection of a data file.  Once this is done the file should be opened, read and parsed.  This process should involve validating the contents of the file against the expected format. If something is missing then an error message should be shown to the user in the form of a dialogue box.<hr>Once the file information has been loaded and parsed, the information should be displayed within the appropriate textual representation elements of the GUI (as developed as part of requirement 1).</html>"  
                  ),
                  BorderLayout.CENTER);


          JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
          ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
             {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                   setVisible(false);
                }
             });



          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          panel.add(ok);
          add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

          setSize(550, 750);

      ImageIcon iconExit = new ImageIcon("exit_icon.png");
      JMenuItem exitMi = new JMenuItem("Exit", iconExit);

        exitMi.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        exitMi.setToolTipText("Exit application");

        exitMi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E,
            ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        exitMi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
     });


   }

}
```

Comment: what validation do you have so far? what doesn't work? and what is it supposed to validate against?

Comment: i need guidance on the validation. The data type below needs vailidating  for errors. but i dont know how to start it.
Title: Effect of Age on Ability
Xlabel: Age
Ylabel: Ability
start: 0
interval: 15
0, 3, 4.2, 7, 5.1, 10, 3.2
Title: <dataset title>
after the file has been validated it should be represented as below. thanks agian

Xlabel: <x-axis label>

Ylabel: <y-axis label>

start: <x-axis start value>

interval: <x-axis interval value>

<data>

Comment: @guess: Validation consists of answering a series of questions with your code.  Are the Title, XLabel, YLabel, start, and interval tags in the line?  Is there at least one non-blank character in the Title?  Is there at least one non-blank character in the XLabel?  Is there at least one non-blank character in the YLabel?  Is the number following start a valid double?  Is the number following interval a valid double?  Is there data?  Are all of the data numbers valid doubles?

Comment: Once this is done the file should be opened, read and parsed.              which i have done but i need to do the validation .               This process should involve validating the contents of the file against the expected format. If something is missing then an error message should be shown to the user in the form of a dialogue box.                           the invalid txt file is shown                                                                Title: Invalid start value given!
Xlabel: A label for X
Ylabel: A label for Y
start: xyz
interval: 1
1, 2, 3

Answer (score 0):

To validate the file content against a format, firstly you obviously need to open the file to analyze its content. This is one way to do that:

```
File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);) {

    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    String line = buffReader.readLine();

    //you must adapt this to your particular format
    String format = "^Title: \w+ Xlabel: \w+ Ylabel: \w+ start: \d+ interval: \d+-\d+ \w+$";

    if(line.matches(format)){

        //file format is valid, do something

    }else{

        //file format is not valid, show error message

    }

} catch (IOException e) {

    //Handle the exception

}
```

Check the [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) documentation and the Java Tutorials for [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://Reading,%20Writing,%20and%20Creating%20Files).

Read about [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), and the method [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) from the String class.

Comment: Thank you, I have already manged to do that the thing that I'm actually struggling with is to validate the selected file but I'm not to sure on where to start. Thanks again.

Comment: How do you need to validate it?

Comment: I needs to validate the contents of the file against the expected format. If something is missing then an error message should be shown to the user in the form of a dialogue box. the contents format is ................................Title: <dataset title>

Xlabel: <x-axis label>

Ylabel: <y-axis label>

start: <x-axis start value>

interval: <x-axis interval value>

<data>    Thanks again x

Comment: Is this the exact format? are the values separated by space or line breaks?

Comment: Yes its separated with both space and colon i need to validate the data provided for errors but don't know how to go about. thanks

Comment: I edited the answer to include the validation using regular expressions againts this format you informed. This may not be the best solution, but it's very straightforward.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. the main issue I am having is the validation for the file I need is to involve validat the contents of the file against the expected format. If something is missing then an error message should be shown to the user in the form of a dialogue box.

Comment: this is an example of an invalid txt file ......................................................................Title: Invalid start value given!
Xlabel: A label for X
Ylabel: A label for Y
start: xyz
interval: 1
1, 2, 3
thanks again I do appreciate it

Comment: But the code above is doing exactly this. What else do you need? Try to elaborate more instead of just throw your homework statement.

Comment: oh i didn't mean to offend any one i didn't realize i wasn't being specific. sorry about that, i have given an invalid example from this the when the file is chosen through the file chooser it must validate to see if there i any errors like so above, ie missing data types, wrong data style ie instead of and int its txt also like missing data which then should show a dialog box when an error is seen/found. thanks again for yr time and help.

Comment: Oh please don't get me wrong, I didn't get offended. I just wans't sure of what you really need. And even after you second explanation, I still feel that this answer can be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: hi how would i go about looking for data as shown as the : being the splitter - Title: Effect of Age on Ability
Xlabel: Age
Ylabel: Ability
start: 0
interval: 15
0, 3, 4.2, 7, 5.1, 10, 3.2